# Interpolating using approxm function goes wrong for one column

Tags: r

I have a data frame which contains three columns.

```
A|B|c
10|0|0
10|5|0
10|10|0
15|0|0
15|5|0
15|10|0
```

When I interpolate the above data frame:

```
df<-approxm(df,206,method="linear")
```

Here is the output:

```
A|B|c
10|0|0
10|1|0
10|2|0
10|3|0
10|4|0
10|5|0
10|6|0
10|7|0
10|8|0
10|9|0
10|10|0
11|8|0
12|6|0
13|4|0
14|2|0
15|0|0
15|1|0
15|2|0
15|3|0
15|4|0
15|5|0
15|6|0
15|7|0
15|8|0
15|9|0
15|10|0
```

Here in this output Column A with values 11,12,13 and 14 are not interpolated properly.

My Expected output is:

```
A|B|c
10|0|0
10|1|0
10|2|0
10|3|0
10|4|0
10|5|0
10|6|0
10|7|0
10|8|0
10|9|0
10|10|0
11|0|0
11|1|0
11|2|0
11|3|0
11|4|0
11|5|0
11|6|0
11|7|0
11|8|0
11|9|0
11|10|0
12|0|0
12|1|0
12|2|0
12|3|0
12|4|0
12|5|0
12|6|0
12|7|0
12|8|0
12|9|0
12|10|0
13|0|0
13|1|0
13|2|0
13|3|0
13|4|0
13|5|0
13|6|0
13|7|0
13|8|0
13|9|0
13|10|0
14|0|0
14|1|0
14|2|0
14|3|0
14|4|0
14|5|0
14|6|0
14|7|0
14|8|0
14|9|0
14|10|0
15|0|0
15|1|0
15|2|0
15|3|0
15|4|0
15|5|0
15|6|0
15|7|0
15|8|0
15|9|0
15|10|0
```

This is my expected output.
But I'm not getting this expected output.
I don't know where my code gets wrong.

Can someone help me out?

Comment: When A goes from 10 to 15, B goes from 10 to 0. That seems in line with your data. What is your expected value for B?

Comment: For B column also the values must go from 0 to 10

Comment: Could you please add an expected output to your post for your current input?

Comment: yes i have added the expected output

Comment: Here is one option using `tidyr` `tidyr::complete(df,A=full_seq(A,1),nesting(B=full_seq(B,1)),fill=list(c=0))`

Comment: @Sara, what you want to do is not interpolation in the usual sense so interpolation functions will not work. I suggest using Suliman's approach

Comment: Thank u @A Suliman  and @Rohit

Answer (score 0):

Complete function worked out.

```
tidyr::complete(df,A=full_seq(A,1),nesting(B=full_seq(B,1)),fill=list(c=0))
```